# Does using vpn for a long time change your location?

Tags: vpn, ip, internet

Is it true that continuously using a different IP make your browser tend to think that your Proxy IP is your main IP. They change your location to the country according to the vpn. So after a period of time although you are not not using VPN .... your network is now virtual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
But as I need to respond with at least 30 characters I will review my answer so:
No.

Comment: Maybe you could be fooled of something like ads appearing in a language different than yours or related to city abroad but... in this case I think that this could be related to cookies on your system.
Also, browsers don't think....

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to understand too many things - VPN, public - private IP addresses.

Generally if you are in private network then you will be assigned a private IP address, and to the world you will be identified using a public IP address and that public IP address would be of your private network (company or college etc.).

VPNs basically hook you inside somebody else's private network. Now once you are in VPN then typically your own IP address (private or public) will be masked and all requests to the destination server will be sent using VPN provider's IP address.

If you have a public IP address, lets say you are connected to internet using some ISP, then you have a public IP address.

In any case, whether you are in private n/w and have private IP, or public IP or in VPN: as long as you do not disconnect and re-connect back you will have same IP address. **So, just by using VPN your location will not change or your own network will not become virtual**; you are already in a virtual network using VPN.

But good think to note that if you are connected to internet using a ISP then as per [DHCP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#DHCP_offer) you will be assigned the IP address for some time, and after that time is elapsed your connection will be broken and you will need to re-connect in which case you will get a new IP address.